# How do I fix the adding value in middle of linked list location?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm creating a single linked list insert beginning, end, and middle of the linked list. After running code inserting the middle is not working in the linked list changing location value randomly and after running it's not getting.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def insertsll(self, value, location):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            if location == 0:
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.head = new_node
            elif location == 1:
                new_node.next = None
                self.tail.next = new_node
                self.tail = new_node
            else:
                temp_node = self.head
                index = 0
                while index < location - 1:
                    temp_node = temp_node.next
                    index += 1
                    next_node = temp_node.next
                    temp_node.next = new_node
                    new_node.next = next_node
                    # if temp_node == self.tail:
                    #     self.tail = new_node




sll = SLinkedList()
sll.insertsll(1, 1)
sll.insertsll(2, 1)
sll.insertsll(3, 1)
sll.insertsll(4, 1)
sll.insertsll(0, 0)
sll.insertsll(60, 3)---> run this random changing location not working in correct location
sll.insertsll(50, 4)---> run this random changing location  not working in correct location

print([node.value for node in sll])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 50, 2, 3, 4]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the iteration in the `while` loop was a little bit too complicated. I think with this code it is more understandable what the insert does. Also, I don't know why you had the `location === 1` check. It seems to be not necessary.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def insertsll(self, value, location):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            if location == 0:
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.head = new_node
            else:
                temp_node = self.head
                index = 0
                
                # Iterate to insert location
                while index < location - 1:
                    index += 1
                    temp_node = temp_node.next

                # Insert new node
                new_node.next = temp_node.next
                temp_node.next = new_node
                
                # Check if new node is tail
                if new_node.next is None:
                    self.tail = new_node



sll = SLinkedList()
sll.insertsll(1, 1)
sll.insertsll(2, 1)
sll.insertsll(3, 1)
sll.insertsll(4, 1)
sll.insertsll(0, 0)
sll.insertsll(60, 3)
sll.insertsll(50, 4)

print([node.value for node in sll])
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 60, 50, 3, 2]
```

P.S.: Such a structure really benefits from a length attribute. This can be used to check if an insert operation is even allowed. Probably, you should consider adding it.

Comment: getting memory error

Comment: With a different input or exactly the code I provided?

Comment: Just what u change in while loop same code written here

Comment: Ok in which line of my posted code is the error occurring? Can you post the full error?

Comment: there is not showing in your code, I think something goes wrong  print([node.value for node in sll])
MemoryError

Comment: did you run the code? Before sending me?

Comment: Yes, works perfectly on my side

Comment: which python version are you running?

Comment: latest version 3.9

Comment: Is your MemoryError meaning that you run out of memory or does it tell you something else?

Comment: i got  it , written this code also elif location == 1:
                new_node.next = None
                self.tail.next = new_node
                self.tail = new_node ,so it's get memory error ,by the this is use for add node end of the linked list .

Comment: `location==1` is not always the tail of your list. In order to update the tail you have to check if the inserted node is the last one, which is done in my code.

Comment: why your output is not getting like this [ 1,2,3,60,50,4], below we called first inserting node in Linkedlist from end we use location ==1 so we called sll.insertionll(1,1), add beginning of linked list use location == 0, for this we called sll.insertionll(2,0) and for insert middle taken as in while loop index < location-1. Although , you said not necessary for location == 1, you didn't taken that parameters location== 1 ,then how did u call sll.insertionsll(1,1),(2,1) etc incase if u call like that output should get like this [0,1,2,3,60,50,4], but your output is [0,1,4,60,50,3,2]

Comment: @JUNO I hope you understand atleast what my concern about output!

Comment: I do not understand your output. If you insert `4` at location `1` it cannot be the tail of your   list. Or do you want to insert a element as tail if location is `1`?

Comment: yes, order wise I'm trying to insert the value 1,2,3,4 at location 1, but your code is getting output unorder

Comment: Ok, the problem is that logically the insertion is not sorting the values. If we have this list `[1,2]` and insert value `3` at location `1`. The result is `[1,3,2]`. If we then add `4` at location `1` we get `[1,4,3,2]`. Either you have to change the order of insertion or change the locations, where you input the values. Do you have more information about what you try to accomplish?